# How can I help to participate in data collection or research work as a field researcher?

Tags: phd, research-process, thesis

To clarify my question, due to length limitations in question part.

For PHD, Researcher allowed to take part as research subject for data collection/analysis? How to include personal accounts of/experiences of a research phenomenon? Thoughts/decision making processes when playing a specific game on world class level?

This then mean a specific game where there are limited /very few really have mastered the game and subjects are not easily contactable. Also potential research participants are a handful 5 to 12.

To explain. If a researcher want to ask how tennis players think his accessibility to the top 20 of the world tennis players are really only 20 and not just anyone around the corner that wannabee play tennis.

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear: do you mean that you are yourself a professional sport player, and you are also doing a PhD specifically on top players in this sport? Please edit the question to clarify. In general scientific principles strongly discourage an author of a study also taking part in the study themselves as a subject.

Comment: Yes, I myself are a gaming esport player, and myself also want to do a PhD specifically on top players in this esport game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step before starting a PhD would be to find a potential supervisor who has some expertise in the research domain (not necessarily the specific topic). First there will be some discussion with this supervisor about the exact research topic and the motivations for the research: a PhD student's expertise in a particular topic is not enough to justify research on this topic, there must be some scientific reasons why this topic is a relevant research area.

Then you will see with your supervisor about the best method(s) to achieve these research goals. Imho it's unlikely that a supervisor would agree with a method which involves you as a subject, but I'm not at all in this kind of domain. In any case your expertise would certainly be useful in contacting subjects and targeting the right research questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Much appreciated. I will then take the stance always be non-bias and that personal bias or experimenter bias are only kept on interpretation on qualitative design. The topic I want to research is is new and not been researched before.